# Получение постов по метке WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Пользуюсь стандартным шаблоном

```
// параметры по умолчанию
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'tag' => 'тут ярлык',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
));

foreach($posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  // формат вывода the_title() ...
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
```

Пробовал вставлять в параметр tag ярлык метки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но видимо это так не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне найти это "альтернативное имя (slug) метки"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В админке есть вся необходимая информация. См. картинку ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо что-то не так делаю